# Where .dmp file is restored after import in oracle?

Tags: oracle, import

I am new to oracle and I have abc.dmp file at c:\abc.dmp location. I want to import this abc.dmp file. I am using the following command.

```
c:\>imp system/mypassword file=c:\abc.dmp full=y
```

I am using Toad for Oracle 12.1 Version. Now after import has been done I don't know where this db has been restored.

I have also created a new user and used the following command.

```
c:\>imp system/mypassword file=c:\abc.dmp fromuser=system touser=testuser2014.
```

After this commend has been executed, I don't know where the db is restored.

Please help me.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Thanks. I have imported dmp file by following steps..

Command to open SQLPLUS

In Command Prompt:
C:> sqlplus / as sysdba

---

Clear Screen:

### SQL> Clear Screen

---

1- First create a new user by

```
SQL> Create user TestUser1 identified by test; -- (test is password)
```

2- Grant Privilages to new created user TestUser

```
SQL> Grant dba, IMP_FULL_DATABASE, EXP_FULL_DATABASE to TestUser;
```

### Optional:

```
You can check which users have the above three grants

SET lines 100 --May not work
COL privilege FOR a50 -- May not work
SELECT grantee, granted_role, default_role 
FROM dba_role_privs 
WHERE granted_role IN ('DBA', 'EXP_FULL_DATABASE', 'IMP_FULL_DATABASE') 
ORDER BY 1,2; -- May not work
```

3- Check TableSpace for this newly created user

```
SQL> select * from dba_users

Note: here you will see that the default DEFAULT_TABLESPACE for TESTUSER is USERS
```

4- Create a new TableSpace for this newly created user "TestUser"

```
SQL> CREATE TABLESPACE tbs_testuser1
    DATAFILE 'tbs_testuser1.dat' 
        SIZE 256M REUSE
        AUTOEXTEND ON NEXT 256M MAXSIZE 2048M

    ONLINE;
```

5- Now Connect this newly created tablespace  'tbs_testuser1' to 'testuser1'.

```
SQL>  ALTER USER TESTUSER1 default tablespace tbs_testuser1 quota unlimited on tbs_testuser1;
```

6- Check whether your 'tbs_testuser1' tablespace is connected to user or not.

```
SQL> select * from dba_users
```

7- In command prompt:

```
c:\>imp system/password file=File Path.dmp log=LOGFileName.log fromuser = <UserName of User from which file is imported> touser=testuser1
```

Answer (score 0):

The data will be restated under the `user/schema` you have just created !  I mean all the objects that reside in the abc.dmp.
 And the datafiles are located under the user tablespace.

Follow this [article](http://www.aodba.com/pt/blog/2014/12/09/exportimport-oracle-schema/) for more details on import/export in Oracle.

Comment: You're missing the obvious thing that an Oracle user is a schema, which (until 12c) equates to a MySQL "database". That is almost certainly why the OP is confused.